# error when get vector value in thrust

Tags: thrust

In the thrust example, there is code expand.cu. But when i want to get the value, has shown error like this 
`error: expression must be a modifiable lvalue` in the line 
`SX = d_output;`

Where is the wrong part? the code is like this

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/gather.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>

#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>


template <typename InputIterator1,
          typename InputIterator2,
          typename OutputIterator>

OutputIterator expand(InputIterator1 first1,
                      InputIterator1 last1,
                      InputIterator2 first2,
                      OutputIterator output)
{
  typedef typename thrust::iterator_difference<InputIterator1>::type difference_type;

  difference_type input_size  = thrust::distance(first1, last1);
  difference_type output_size = thrust::reduce(first1, last1);

  // scan the counts to obtain output offsets for each input element
  thrust::device_vector<difference_type> output_offsets(input_size, 0);
  thrust::exclusive_scan(first1, last1, output_offsets.begin()); 

  // scatter the nonzero counts into their corresponding output positions
  thrust::device_vector<difference_type> output_indices(output_size, 0);
  thrust::scatter_if
    (thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>(0),
     thrust::counting_iterator<difference_type>(input_size),
     output_offsets.begin(),
     first1,
     output_indices.begin());

  // compute max-scan over the output indices, filling in the holes
  thrust::inclusive_scan
    (output_indices.begin(),
     output_indices.end(),
     output_indices.begin(),
     thrust::maximum<difference_type>());

  // gather input values according to index array (output = first2[output_indices])
  OutputIterator output_end = output; thrust::advance(output_end, output_size);
  thrust::gather(output_indices.begin(),
                 output_indices.end(),
                 first2,
                 output);

  // return output + output_size
  thrust::advance(output, output_size);
  return output;
}


int main(void)
{
  int counts[] = {3,5,2,0,1,3,4,2,4};
  int values[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

  size_t input_size  = sizeof(counts) / sizeof(int);
  size_t output_size = thrust::reduce(counts, counts + input_size);

  // copy inputs to device
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_counts(counts, counts + input_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_values(values, values + input_size);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_output(output_size);

  // expand values according to counts
  expand(d_counts.begin(), d_counts.end(),
         d_values.begin(),
         d_output.begin());


  std::cout << "d_output: " ;
  for(int i=0; i<output_size; i++)
    std::cout << d_output[i] << " , ";

  //d::cout << d_output[i] << " , ";  
  thrust::device_vector<int> SX[output_size];
  //SX = d_output;
  thrust::copy(d_output.begin() , d_output.end(), SX.begin());


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a device vector of the length `output_size` as

```
thrust::device_vector<int> SX(output_size);
```

Using `[]` means array of device vectors.